# Specific blinking on p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am new to `p5.js` and coding in general and having fun trying to code a mini scenario looking like a video game.

I'd like to put a blinking effect that would look like this, on some text:

[image]

I found a way to do it using `frameRate(2);`, the problem is I have some animations on the background that need 60fps and not 2, so I'm a bit confused on how to do it because it seems I can't use 2 different frame rates on a single file (?)

I already tried using `if (frameCount % 30 === 0)`, but the text only appears once a frame making it difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the frame rate is probably not a good solution to any problem, so you're right to keep looking.

There's probably a better way, but without seeing the rest of your code (and being a little rusty in Processing myself), I'm not sure what that is. So going in the direction you're heading, I'll note that when you say `frameCount%30===0`, the frameCount will only be divisible by 30 twice a second, so it will only blink twice, very briefly, every second.

Instead, what about `if(frameCount % 60 < 30)`? This should show the text for the first half of every second. You can adjust these parameters to your liking: `if(frameCount % 120 < 60)` would slow the blink down to a full second, and there's no reason you need to be bound to multiples of 60. `if(frameCount % 100 < 50)` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks you it's exactly what I needed !!